# Managing FTPs for multiple business units

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, ftp, etl

I've run into an issue with the amount of licenses I have available to use in out ETL generator (Dell Boomi).  Using this to push data into a 5 different business units and file dropping to the Enhanced SFTP from Marketing Cloud.

The question is: can I utilize 1 FTP for all the business units?  Or is each business unit only able to reference their specific MC FTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Administration > File Locations

You can connect to any other FTP that you may need.
Caveat is that running multiple imports onto one FTP import folder is going to get messy.

Anyone know if there's a daily volume limit on these?

Comment: Do you want to use an external or an Salesforce SFTP? If you take a salesforce i am kean to know if there is a SFTP GB Limitation because there is such a limitation for Data Extension Storage 1GB for Basic, 15GB for Pro, 45GB for Corporate and 100GB for Enterprise.

Comment: Looks like there's no documentation for size limits. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199556/limitations-for-import-from-enhanced-ftp-in-sfmc